# Deployment error on sobject without message

Tags: salesforcedx, sobject, illuminatedcloud

I am pushing Account sobject on save. File is CustomData__c.object, not multiple for each field. It says "Deployed with status SUCCEEDED_PARTIAL, but no error is displayed. They are displayed in log file though. Error when deploying via sfdx:  Cannot set sharingModel to ControlledByParent on a CustomObject without a MasterDetail relationship field.

Is it possible to see that error in ide?

Comment: And... does your csv explicitly state that it's setting the sharingModel as ControlledByParent and the object in question that's being inserted is not set as the detail object in Master-Detail in the target org?

Comment: @akarnid  Yes, error is due to the fact that the master detail field is not in the metadata of this file. But my problem is that error is not displayed in ide and its so much pain to look into multiple error via sfdx or log.